# converting arabic numbers to english cgfloat returns in english

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

im using the below function to convert numbers from english to arabic:

```
-(NSString *)convertEnNumberToArabic:(NSString *) number{
    NSString *text;
    NSDecimalNumber *someNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:number];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"];
    [formatter setLocale:gbLocale];
    text = [formatter stringFromNumber:someNumber];
    return text;
}
 NSString *convertedCharge = [self convertEnNumberToArabic:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [self deliveryCharge]]];
```

after im getting the arabic number, if i want to convert it to float, its returning to english as below:

```
CGFloat floatCharge =  (CGFloat)[convertedCharge floatValue];
```

so the floatcharge is returning the value in english again, how can i solve this issue? i need the values to be as cgfloats

Comment: Probably just `CGFloat floatCharge = [self deliveryCharge];` You already have the value as a `float`, haven't you?

Comment: [self deliveryCharge] return the value as float, and in eglish, convertedCharge is the value of [self deliveryCharge ] as string and in arabic, this value i want to convert it to float and keep it in arabic

Comment: You are confusing a number and its string representation. A number is not English or Arabic, it represents a universal value. Only string representation of a number can be localized. `CGFloat` is neither English or Arabic.